# can't create aws instance that image id does not exist?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I am following the aws 's [tutorial on node.js](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-examples.html) to create a aws instance

```
var ec2 = new AWS.EC2();

var params = {
  ImageId: "ami-2d4aa444",
  InstanceType: 't1.micro',
  MinCount: 1, MaxCount: 1
};

// Create the instance
ec2.runInstances(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) { console.log("Could not create instance", err); return; }

  var instanceId = data.Instances[0].InstanceId;
  console.log("Created instance", instanceId);

  // Add tags to the instance
  params = {Resources: [instanceId], Tags: [
    {Key: 'Name', Value: instanceName}
  ]};
  ec2.createTags(params, function(err) {
    console.log("Tagging instance", err ? "failure" : "success");
  });
});
```

it gave me a error saying:

```
Could not create instance { [InvalidAMIID.NotFound: The image id '[ami-2d4aa444]
' does not exist]
  message: 'The image id \'[ami-2d4aa444]\' does not exist',
  code: 'InvalidAMIID.NotFound',
  name: 'InvalidAMIID.NotFound',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false }
```

How can I find a valid a image id on the aws console ?

Comment: Whenever you talk about AMI image ID you should always talk about a Region as well - these IDs are not universal and can only be used in a context of a specific Region. It can be nicely seen in [Ubuntu Cloud Images](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/saucy/release-20131113/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see you specifying your region anywhere which would probably explain why it can't be found - you didn't tell it where to look:

> AWS.config.region = "us-east-1";    (for example)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the default `am-ids` given below for your specified region:

```
ap-northeast-1  ami-50eaed51
ap-southeast-1  ami-f95875ab
eu-central-1    ami-ac1524b1
eu-west-1       ami-823686f5
sa-east-1       ami-c770c1da
us-east-1       ami-4ae27e22
us-west-1       ami-d1180894
cn-north-1      ami-fe7ae8c7
us-gov-west-1   ami-cf5630ec
ap-southeast-2  ami-890b62b3
us-west-2       ami-898dd9b9
```

Check [this link for instance-types](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-types.html).